# Краш при выполнении условия

Tags: java, android

```
public class forTimer extends Fragment {

    public Chronometer timerOtd;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.laytimer, container, false);

        timerOtd= rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timerOtd.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        timerOtd.start();
        timerOtd.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener(){

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        - timerOtd.getBase();

                if (elapsedMillis > 2000) {
                    try {
                        Uri notify= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                        Ringtone r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext().getApplicationContext(), notify);
                        r.play();

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    timerOtd.stop();
                }

            }

        });

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Ошибок не выдает, но при запуске приложения, при выполнении условия (спустя две секунды) происходит краш. А хотелось бы чтоб проигрывался рингтон и останавливался таймер

Comment: Что отладчик говорит?

Comment: @iksuy Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket' и все

Comment: @ЛаврикНеизвестный, На какой строчке падает?

Comment: @post_zeew Ringtone r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext().getApplicationContext(), notify); ему не нравится getContext. Нужен API level23, а в моем проекте стоит 17 минимальный. Как выполнить данный метод в моем случае?

Comment: `getContext().getApplicationContext()` замените на `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: А на реальном устройстве не пробовали? Не помню, что но было такое что на на эмулятор просто переставал работать, а на реальном телефоне все работало замечательно.

Comment: @tosh17 я на реальном устройстве и запускаю. На эмуляторе нет аудиофайлов

Comment: @post_zeew не падает, но и звуков не воспроизводит.

Comment: @post_zeew оформите как ответ, (в принципе вопрос с крашем решен) получите + к карме

Comment: Добавил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить `application context` от контекста, возвращаемого методом `getContext()` класса `Fragment`, который доступен для API level 23 и выше.

Так как приложение запускается на меньшем API level, то оно падает.

Для получения `application context` внутри фрагмента, можно воспользоваться цепочкой методов:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Также, `application context` можно получить, переопределив класс `Application` и добавив соответствующее поле и геттер.

Вообще говоря, в метод `getRingtone(...)` можно просто передать ссылку на активити, ведь там требуется любой класс, в иерархии наследования которого имеется класс `Context`.

Comment: А лучше заинжектить в даггер

Comment: @Flippy отркыл для себя даггер ?))))и чем же лучше хотелось бы узнать)

Comment: @elik, :$ не )) только на пути к этому, решил за него конкретно взяться с этого дня. Чем лучше тоже не знаю, ничего пока не знаю, просто часто слышу "заинжектить" :D

Comment: @Flippy почитай про паттерны )это всего лишь паттер который реализован красиво)

Comment: @elik, меня слегка смущает, что библиотеки заставляют всех писать код одинаково